# Vue.JS Component Not Appearing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-material

I'm attempting to use Vue Material on a Vue Router Dashboard page, but I'm trying to store the panel in a separate file. I'm absolutely clueless as to why this is not working, I've spent the last 2 hours googling this issue and I don't have anything. Even using the Vue chrome extension doesn't show it, which rules out styling. Putting a red background color on the component does work, yet it still does not work. And also, please forgive my bad code-- I'm about 3 days into Vue.

```
<template>
    <div class="page-container md-layout-row">
        <md-app>
            <md-app-toolbar class="md-primary">
                <span class="md-title">{{ usernameTitleCase }}</span>
            </md-app-toolbar>
            <PagePanel></PagePanel>
            <md-app-content>
                <div class="user">
                    <h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
                    <h2>{{ user.customThing }}</h2>
                    <h3>{{ user.id }}</h3>
                </div>
            </md-app-content>
        </md-app>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import PagePanel from '@/components/panel.vue';

    export default {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        components: {
            PagePanel
        },
        data() {
            return {}
        },
        computed: {
            usernameTitleCase() {
                const letters = this.user.username.split('');
                letters[0] = letters[0].toUpperCase();
                return letters.join('')
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .md-app {
        min-height: 350px;
    }

    .md-drawer {
        width: 230px;
        max-width: calc(100vw - 125px);
    }
</style>
```

Component File Here:

```
<template>
    <md-app-drawer md-permanent="full">
        <md-toolbar class="md-transparent" md-elevation="0">
            Navigation
        </md-toolbar>

        <md-list>
            <md-list-item>
                <md-icon>move_to_inbox</md-icon>
                <span class="md-list-item-text">Inbox</span>
            </md-list-item>

            <md-list-item>
                <md-icon>send</md-icon>
                <span class="md-list-item-text">Sent Mail</span>
            </md-list-item>

            <md-list-item>
                <md-icon>delete</md-icon>
                <span class="md-list-item-text">Trash</span>
            </md-list-item>

            <md-list-item>
                <md-icon>error</md-icon>
                <span class="md-list-item-text">Spam</span>
            </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
    </md-app-drawer>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'PagePanel'
    }
</script>
```

I'm also NOT in production mode and am not getting any errors in console.

Comment: _"Putting a red background color on the component does work, yet it still does not work."_ You lost me there

Comment: Sorry-- I mean let's say in the panel file, I were to apply a style such as:
<style> body { background-color: red;} </style>. That would appear and work @blex.

Comment: So... what doesn't work, specifically? I can already tell you that your `user` property is NOT reactive. `user` needs to be declared in data()

Comment: I am aware about the user thing, this is just a temporary thing and it wasn’t working when I was using the set thing. What isn’t working is when I try to import the panel it’s just not rendering.

Comment: Try using `<page-panel></page-panel>`, and tell us if that changes anything

Comment: The render errors are probably causing the component not to render. You see errors in the console?

Comment: @Cooper that's not what I meant. I meant using `<page-panel></page-panel>` in your dashboard template, but keeping it as `PagePanel` in your JS

Comment: Sorry @blex I really don't understand. Here's my current code: https://hastebin.com/sohogokamu.xml I'm very confused-- sorry.

Comment: @Cooper like this? https://hastebin.com/jeqiludogo.xml

Comment: If that doesn't solve the issue, it's hard to tell what else could cause it  I tried your templates "as-is" in a JSFiddle, and it worked after making this change. It might be easier to help you if you provide a Git repository with a full example reproducing the problem, if you are able to (does not need to be your entire project, just enough so that we can install it locally, run it, and see the problem happening)

Comment: So sorry! I’m at dinner right now, I’ll try this when I get back. Thank you a lot though!

Comment: Hey @blex, just tested out your solution. Unfortunately, it did not work. I was wondering if you could add my Discord (Cooper#6969), for me to share the git with you? If you can't or don't have the time-- I completely understand. Once again, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to spot, but towards the end of [this page of the VueMaterial docs](https://vuematerial.io/components/app), it says:

> In these examples we have 3 distinct areas: `Toolbar`, `Drawer` and `Content`. You should create them using the following tags:
>
> - `md-app-toolbar`: ...
> - `md-app-drawer`: ...
> - `md-app-content`: ...
>
> **Any other tag passed as a direct child of the md-app tag will be ignored.** The component will only look for these three tags and choose the right placement for them.

Fortunately, they [added the ability to use slots](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/pull/1387/files) (but didn't document them, you have to look at merge requests to see it). You can use them like so:

```
<template>
    <div class="page-container md-layout-row">
        <md-app>
            <md-app-toolbar> ... </md-app-toolbar>
            <page-panel slot="md-app-drawer"></page-panel>
            <md-app-content> ... </md-app-content>
        </md-app>
    </div>
</template>
```

However, note that the `slot` value can only be one of the 3 values defined above.